# App icon is not showing in CallKit UI

Tags: ios, ios10, callkit

I have configured my Provider Configuration for CallKit iOS. In which I have also set '**iconTemplateImageData**' for displaying app icon in CallKit UI. But app icon is not showing. It shows a white square box.

[image]

Provider Configuration Code:

```
    CXProviderConfiguration *configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", _title]];
    configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1;
    configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1;
    UIImage *callkitIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon"];
    configuration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(callkitIcon);

    _callKitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
    [_callKitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    _callKitCallController = [[CXCallController alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

I have used AppIcon images in '**Images.xcassets**' with sizes: -
**1x:** 40*40, **2x:** 80*80, **3x:** 120*120

Please help why my app icon is not showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this demo app may help u : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I have already seen it. Here also they used same methodology for setting AppIcon in configuration. Like.......    if let iconMaskImage = UIImage(named: "IconMask") {
            providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(iconMaskImage)
        }

Comment: open var iconTemplateImageData: Data? // Image should be a square with side length of 40 points

Comment: I know the size should be 40 points as I have explained above. I have also checked that Apple has used in above provided link same as I have used.

Answer (score 12):

This is likely because you are using your AppIcon image, which is a fully opaque image, i.e. no part of that image is transparent or has alpha=0.

To get the desired effect, you have to use a different image which is partly (or mostly) transparent. The native in-call UI will only use the alpha channel of the image you provide, so it ignores colors. I suggest following the example in the [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app and providing a secondary PNG image in your image asset catalog with transparency.

Comment: I edited my existing logo such that only the borders are visible, the rest of it is transparent. Final result looks cool. Thnx @Stuart M, it works on my side. Your answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code in order to set app name and app icon for incoming VOIP calls

```
let localizedName = NSLocalizedString("App-Name", comment: "Name of application")
let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: localizedName)
providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImage.init(named: "appicon-Name")?.pngData()
```

Note: Your app icon must be transparent. result will be like in below image

[image]